# Detect multitouch with Ontouch listener Android

Tags: android, imageview, multi-touch

I currently have an imageview element that upon being touched, that tests if the action is an actiondown event, and if it is, it gets the coordinates of the touch with getraw(x or y) and then carries out an action based on those coordinates. How would I implement this to get two sets of coordinates from a two finger multitouch event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` action define in `MotionEvent`.  This is the event that will get called when additional fingers come down after the first `ACTION_DOWN` triggers.  You can use methods like `getActionMasked()` to assist you in determining which finger events are related to.

[MotionEvent Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)

HTH

Answer (score 2):

[This is a nice example](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html)