# Gesture in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect multitouch with Ontouch listener Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002003/detect-multitouch-with-ontouch-listener-android)

I have a question about detecting touches. This is any method in android to detect if user touch screen one finger or two at the same time? I have image view and I would like to know that I touch that picture one or two fingers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same [View.onTouch(View, MotionEvent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch%28android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent%29) you use for the touch detection. The MotionEvent object has the [getPointerCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPointerCount%28%29), that will return the number of pointers of data contained in this event. If it retunrns a `value > 1`, you have a multitouch. It requires at least `Android 5`