# Registering Coords for two fingers

Tags: java, android

I want to build an android application that would register the x,y for two fingers on the screen at the same time.  Is this possible or does android not allow that?

Comment: The 'pinch to zoom' feature of some Android apps. seems to suggest multiple contact points are possible, but I do not know how easy it would be to adapt that to your purpose.  What is your purpose in doing this, BTW?

Comment: I just want to calculate the midpoint between them...

Comment: OK - and why would I as a user, not want to just tap on the screen in the middle of the 2 places I might have put my fingers?  Try to explain it as a feature that would make **me** as a potential user think this is a 'must have' app.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, This question says nothing about pinch zooming - just handling multi-touch gestures. It is also not a question about app design or user experience - those all come with experience.

Comment: *"It is also not a question about app design or user experience.."*  My question was about app. design and user experience.  Your point being, what?

Comment: I don't have an idea for it just yet but I was wondering if it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

Your View can keep track of multiple touches in its `onTouch` method be monitoring the events with the `ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` flag. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002003/detect-multitouch-with-ontouch-listener-android), and its links, for more help.